# Can anyone identify this disease on carmen peppers?

Tags: diseases, peppers

This has happened to three carmen peppers on this plant.  Grown in zone 5.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like

> Blossom-end rot is an abiotic disorder of peppers caused by calcium deficiency during fruit development.

Image 2 to from [this source](https://www.lsuagcenter.com/portals/our_offices/departments/plant-pathology-crop-physiology/plant_disease_clinic/disease_image_gallery/herbs_vegetables/peppers/pepper-diseases)

Comment: I had ruled that out because I thought that started on the very bottom of the fruit.

Comment: Make a vertical cut in the bottom: It most likely starts on the very bottom **inside** the fruit.

Comment: Interesting!  I already trashed them but I will investigate if any others pop up